# Compress PDF generated using iOS UIGraphics

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uigraphicscontext

I have generated the PDF using the below code

```
let pdfData = NSMutableData()
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768), nil)
guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
for view in PdfPages {
     UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
     view.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)
 }
 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

I want to know if there is any way by which I can compress the PDF.
Note: I am not using any image in any of my PdfPages.
Thanks in advance.